# How to use rails 3.2 engine in rails 4.1 engine development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-engines

When developing rails 4.1 engine module_infox, there include gem authentify which is developed in rails 3.2 in module_infox's gemfile:

```
gem 'authentify', :path => '../authentify'
```

Gem authentify sits locally and its gemfile.lock was deleted to remove the version lock.

When `bundle install` under module_infox, there is an error:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    authentify (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      rails (= 3.2.12) x86-mingw32

    module_infox (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      rails (4.1.0.beta1)
```

Based on our reading, old version gem can be used in newer version gem. Both `gemfile.lock` in authentify and module_infox were deleted before `bundle install`. But there is the same error. What's right way to do so?

Comment: You can check if authentify.gemspec has hard dependency on Rails 3.2.12

Comment: Yes, authentify.gemspec is specifying the rails version of 3.2.12. Authentify was developed under rails 3.2.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the specific dependency on Rails 3.2.12 on authentify gem is the reason of conflict.

#### Solution 1: Direct fix

The most intuitive solution would be changing this hard dependency. Say, revise the gemspec as `rails, '> 3.2'`.

However, your authentify gem itself may not be ready for Rails 4 yet. So using this would be a bit aggressive.

#### Solution 2: Use git brach

The better alternative is to add a branch in authentify gem say "rails-4", then change the gemspec as above.

Then you need to specify this git branch in Gemfile.

If you use Github to host this gem

```
gem 'authentify', git: 'git://github.com/username/authentify', branch: 'rails-4'
```

If you are not going to opensource this gem, you can still use local path. But you need to setup Bundle to recognize it.

```
$ bundle config local.authentify ~/Work/git/authentify
```

Then set it in Gemfile

```
# gem 'authentify', :github => 'authentify/authentify', :branch => 'master'
```

I commented out the last line of code because I just copied it from Bundle doc but not verified that before. You can check the doc and experiment by yourself. http://bundler.io/v1.2/git.html

Comment: Billy, my understanding of your post is that solution 2 is basically the same as solution 1. The only difference is that in solution 2 authentify is branched out. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, basically same. #2 is used when you are not ready to upgrade master of authentify yet.

Comment: If we use solution 2, do we need to upgrade the branch of authentify to rails 4.1? Or we can make 3.2 authentify working with rails 4.1 app without any change. We have several rails 3.2 engines and there will be a lots of upgrading if it is necessary. Thanks.

Comment: The only necessary thing you must make is to change the Rails dependency there, say `rails, '>3'`. For others, you can change until you find bugs.

Comment: If we want to develop the engine with rails 3.2.12 and make it available for other rails version above, can we do: s.add_dependency "rails", ">3.2.12" in gemspec?

Comment: Yes you can, though a bit vague :)